# :noweb :tangle just not working

Tags: org-mode, tangle

I'm trying to get literate programming with `:noweb` syntax working in org-mode. I think I'm down to about the minimum case:

```
#+TITLE: Console Tic Tac Toe
#+SUBTITLE: A Literate Program in EMACS Org-Mode
#+AUTHOR: Charlie Martin
#+STARTUP: showall

#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle yes :noweb 
  import sys
  import os

  def main(args):
      <<initialize-the-game-board>>

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main(sys.argv)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: initialize-the-game-board
#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle yes :noweb
  board = [[-1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
#+END_SRC
```

but when I tangle it I get:

```
import sys
import os

def main(args):
    <<initialize-the-game-board>>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)

board = [[-1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

I've tried permuting the argument, flags, and so on to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the specification is slightly finicky.

The following should do what you want:

```
#+TITLE: Console Tic Tac Toe
#+SUBTITLE: A Literate Program in EMACS Org-Mode
#+AUTHOR: Charlie Martin
#+STARTUP: showall

#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle yes :noweb tangle
  import sys
  import os

  def main(args):
      <<initialize-the-game-board>>

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main(sys.argv)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: initialize-the-game-board
#+BEGIN_SRC python
  board = [[-1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
#+END_SRC
```

The two changes are:

1. You need to specify `:noweb tangle` rather than just `:noweb`. (`:noweb yes` also works.)
2. For the second block that is being included, you must not include `:tangle yes` or it will be included twice in the output (once inserted into the first block, as desired and the second as a block in its own right). You can use `:noweb` or `:noweb yes` for the second block, but it neither helps nor hinders, so I've also removed it. (`:noweb-ref initialize-the-game-board` could serve as an alternative to the `#+NAME:` line.)

Some more minimal noweb examples:

http://www.draketo.de/light/english/minimal-example-for-literate-programming-noweb-emacs-org-mode

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493227/emacs-org-mode-how-to-create-literate-programs-with-noweb-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with some help from the org-mode list, I found the magical incantation: `:tangle yes :noweb yes` in the *root* source block.

```
#+TITLE: Console Tic Tac Toe
#+SUBTITLE: A Literate Program in EMACS Org-Mode
#+AUTHOR: Charlie Martin
#+STARTUP: showall

#+BEGIN_SRC python :tangle yes :noweb yes
  import sys
  import os

  def main(args):
      <<initialize-the-game-board>>

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main(sys.argv)
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: initialize-the-game-board
#+BEGIN_SRC python 
  board = [[-1 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
#+END_SRC
```